# Is there a way to read and plot the nth file in a folder in python?

Tags: python, pandas, file, plot

Im trying to find a quick and easy way to read and plot the nth csv file in a folder,

im currently working with the following, to read all files in the folder>

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
  
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))  
  
for file in csv_files:
      
    # read adn plot the csv file
    Data = pd.read_csv(file,header=33)
    sns.lineplot(x=Data['x'],y=Data['y'],data=Data)
```

but is there a way to read and plot every 4th file for example?

Comment: `for file in csv_files[::4]:`?

Comment: but how do you define nth file? might be different from the OS, python, glob… perspective

Comment: Ordered how? Directories can have an OS-defined order which is out of your control (commonly order of creation, but with the OS possibly reusing slots from deleted files) but many end-user utilities (including Python's `os.listdir()`, as opposed to `os.scandir()`) will sort them alphabetically using the invoking user's locale settings.

Comment: `glob` by definition also sorts, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file, count in enumerate(csv_files, start=1):
       if count % 4:
            Data = pd.read_csv(file,header=33)
            sns.lineplot(x=Data['x'],y=Data['y'],data=Data)
```

`count` will keep increasing and only read every 4th file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter variable (which is a very beginner approach, but easy to start).

```
counter = 0
for file in csv_files:
    # Increase the counter value for each iteration
    counter = counter +1  
    # read adn plot the csv file
    Data = pd.read_csv(file,header=33)
    # For example, you want to print the third file
    if counter == 3:
        sns.lineplot(x=Data['x'],y=Data['y'],data=Data)
```